# Product images not showing but loading fine in Category pages

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, theme, product-attribute

I've hit a wall with this issue. I cloned our live site for development purposes. It worked fine, we upgraded from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.1.0. We optimized images on the media folder and replaced the current ones via ftp, we re-indexed and shortly after realized images or custom options weren't showing up on the product pages. I went through every single suggestion I found online

Commenting out All options -

1. `Indexes in htaccess`,
2. `Rewriting to All -indexes`
3. `Deleting cache,`
4. `Cleaning out cache and re-indexing`
5. `Deleting .htaccess in media`
6. `Increasing php memory limit`
7. `Changing file permissions`

etc.

The images show up on category pages and in the backend, but when going to product pages they're not there, when inspecting element they're not even being called, I also added new products with new images and those items show up blank in the product page.

it's just a `blank spot in the page`. I'm at a loss what can be the issue ?

**edit: Adding media.phtml code**

```
     ?>
     <?php
        $_product = $this->getProduct();
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    ?>
    <?php if ($_product->getImage() != 'no_selection' && $_product->getImage()): ?>
    <p class="product-image product-image-zoom">
        <?php
            $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
            echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
        ?>
    </p>
    <p class="zoom-notice" id="track_hint"><?php echo $this->__('Double click on above image to view full picture') ?></p>
    <div class="zoom">
        <img id="zoom_out" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/slider_btn_zoom_out.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Zoom Out') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zoom Out') ?>" class="btn-zoom-out" />
        <div id="track">
            <div id="handle"></div>
        </div>
        <img id="zoom_in" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/slider_btn_zoom_in.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Zoom In') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zoom In') ?>" class="btn-zoom-in" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
            product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint');
        });
    //]]>
    </script>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p class="product-image">
        <?php
            $_img = '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(265).'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
            echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
        ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
    <div class="more-views">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('More Views') ?></h2>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->getGalleryUrl($_image) ?>', 'gallery', 'width=300,height=300,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56); ?>" width="56" height="56" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**edit 2: Catalog.xml code**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                <!--
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
                -->
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                    <label>Alert Urls</label>
                </block>
```

**Final Edit:** I ended up scrapping and using a fresh install.

Comment: please show code of prduct page?

Comment: @AmitBera The view.phtml or html from the browser? Right now its running on a default magento theme

Comment: yes. view.phtml code

Comment: sorry,put media.phtml code instead of view.phtml

Comment: ok added, I found it in this directory: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view is that correct ?

Comment: yes. if it not exit your  theme template folder

Comment: yes that should be it, the website is running on default magento theme, its in the same directory i got view.phtml from.

Comment: please clear media/catalog/product/cache and ckd  and let me know

Comment: I cleared cache, but I don't know what ckd is @AmitBera

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23071/discussion-between-amit-bera-and-jeff).

Comment: Do you have following block in your `path_to_theme/layout/catalog.xml`?

`<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml">
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.media.after" as="after" />
                </block>`

Comment: The one I have is magento default and it's slightly different, I added it to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

**catalog/product/view.phtml**
Check if this template has the following:

```
<div class="product-img-box">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
</div>
```

Also, turn on the Magento logs and refresh the cache's and see if an error pops up in the logs when you reload the product view page.